# Regex to match a combination of digits, but shuoldn't match some some other patterns

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to match the following things.

```
10/1987 - 10/1987
2/1987 - 12/1987
More clearly:

 ["one" or "two digit"]["any symbol mainly [/-]][a space if there followed by slash or hiphen [-/]["one" or "two digit"]["any symbol mainly [/-]]
```

This is the output I am having.

https://regex101.com/r/cN9eJ0/1

Comment: @vks - Just add gmi in the right box column. The updated link is https://regex101.com/r/cN9eJ0/2

Answer (score 1):

```
\b((?:(?<!\/)[\d]{1,2}[\/\s-]{0,3}(?!\d{3}\b)\d{2,4})\s*-\s*\b(?:(?<!\/)[\d]{1,2}[\/\s-]{0,3}(?!\d{3}\b)\d{2,4}))
```

Just add anchors to limit partial matches.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cN9eJ0/5

Comment: Thanks dude. Seems working at first glance. I will check further combinations.